# The notion of "Admissible" and "Permitted" in the context of convolution with distributions and hypocontinuity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions, tempered-distributions

I am reading the paper "On Convolutions" (1958) and have encountered the notion of "Admissible" and "Permitted" spaces.

In p.17-18 of the above paper, it says that an admissible space $E$ is a locally convex space of distributions with $\mathcal{D} \subset E \subset \mathcal{D}'$ with

1. the inclusions being continuous
2. $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $E$.

Also, for an admissible space $E$, it further defines the notion of "Permitted" by introducing regularizations $\{ \rho_k \}$ and multiplicators $\{ \alpha_k \}$. Here,

1. $\{ \rho_k \}$ is a sequence of nonnegative, even functions with $\int \rho_k=1$ and support tending to $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. $0 \leq \alpha_k \leq 1$, $\alpha_k \to 1$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and $\{ \alpha_k \}$ is bounded in $\mathfrak{B}$.
3. Then, $E$ is permitted if $\alpha_k (T * \rho_k) \to T$ and $(\alpha_k T) * \rho_k) \to T$ in $E$ for all $T \in E$.

In the above 2, I was not able to understand what "bounded in $\mathfrak{B}$" exactly means. So, I looked for the cited reference but it is in French...

http://sites.mathdoc.fr/OCLS/pdf/OCLS_1950__14__220_0.pdf

Could anyone please explain to me what exactly the multiplicator is? Also, according to the above definitions, does $C^\infty( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ with the Frechet topology qualify as the permitted space?

Comment: Without access to the paper *On convolution* it is not possible to answer your question. Note that Schwartz used $\mathcal E$ for the space of $C^\infty$ functions with the topology of uniform convergence on all compact sets of all derivatives. Maybe, the requirement is that $\alpha_k$ converges to the constant function $1$ in $\mathcal E=C^\infty$ and is contained and bounded in $E$.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAIQw7AJahcKEwjAs4TcnZj_AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fjournal-of-science-of-the-hiroshima-university-series-a-mathematics-physics-chemistry%2Fvolume-22%2Fissue-1%2FOn-Convolutions%2F10.32917%2Fhmj%2F1555639564.pdf&psig=AOvVaw05NlfOwIW5xBMTlxWnHoFt&ust=1685370809909395

Comment: Does the above link work? It is the "On Convolutions" paper I mentioned.

Comment: The link works. I don't have access to Schwartz's *Théorie des Distributions* at the moment but, contrary to my comment above, Schwartz writes $(\mathcal E)$ for the space of smooth functions or $(\mathcal D)$ for smooth functions with compact support (the somewhat strange parentheses  are no longer in use, afaik). In the definition of permitted spaces boundedness in $(\mathcal B)$ is required so that, most likely, this is another space of functions or distributions which I do not recall right now (maybe smooth functions with all derivatives bounded on $\mathbb R^n$). I'll check this tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help. I wish I were able to read French...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors Yoshinaga and Ogata of *On concolutions* use Schwartz's notation for spaces of functions and distributions. The requirements for the sequence of smooth functions $\alpha_k$ with values in $[0,1]$ are convergence to the constant function $1$ in the space $(\mathcal E)$ of all smooth functions, which means $\alpha_k\to 1$ and $\partial^\beta\alpha_k\to 0$ uniformly on compact sets for all multi-indices $\beta\neq 0$, as well as boundedness in the space $(\mathcal B)$ of all smooth functions with all derivatives bounded in $\mathbb R^n$ (this space $(\mathcal B)$ is introduced on page 199 of Schwartz's *Théorie des Distributions*), which means $$\sup\{|\partial^\beta \alpha_k(x)|: x\in\mathbb R^n, k\in\mathbb N\}<\infty$$ for each multi-index $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation. So, it seems quite clear that $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ with the Frechet topology qualifies as a permitted space.